# Higher-order functions: function that change other function. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, function

could anyone explain to me what is this function doing and how does it work? I'm a beginner and I don't get it.

It is from Eloquent JavaScript.

```js
function noisy(f) {
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('calling with', args);
    let result = f(...args);
    console.log('called with', args, ', returned', result);
  }
  return result;
}
noisy(Math.min)(3, 2, 1);
```

Comment: f is a function and noisy returns a function

Comment: That last `return result;` statement is probably supposed to be inside the returned `=>` function, not outside.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: @Pointy It isn't. It's an example from a book

Comment: @SylwiaGrzegorczyk trust us, the book is wrong. the second `return` will never be hit!

Comment: [Higher-order functions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23535316)

Comment: Nice find @VLAZ not only is this the exact same example, it's obviously been fixed in a later edition of this book!

Comment: [The book doesn't have a second return](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_xxCc98lOBK)

Comment: See [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/2873538)

Comment: @SylwiaGrzegorczyk The output you are getting is not because of `return result;` because `result` can not be accessed outside the first return statement.

Comment: @Jamiec weirdly, I tried SO's search (I know it's bad) *and* [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=function+noisy%28f%29) but didn't find a question about it. I just used a regular search engine to find the reference in the book and got...the other SO question...

Comment: @Pointy The book is correct. The code copied by her is wrong. [Check This](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_xxCc98lOBK) VLAZ mentioned it before...