# Understanding higher order JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, function, vue.js

I am learning Higher-order functions from Eloquent JavaScript, I did my research for a similar question but was unable to find it. There was a similar question related to mine from the same topic and same chapter but it was a basic one.
Here's the link for a similar one:
[Higher-order functions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535316/higher-order-functions-in-javascript).

I am facing a problem with the below code:

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

let unless = (test, then) => {
  if(!test)then();
};

repeat(3, n => {
  unless(n%2 == 1, () => {
    console.log(`${n} is even`);
  });
});

// Output:
/  → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

1. How does this higher-order function work?
2. How does the looping work in order to determine whether the number is even or odd?

Comment: *"There was a similar question related to mine from the same topic and same chapter but it was a basic one"* Please always link the questions that you think may be related.

Comment: Sure will edit within a few minutes.

Comment: Truly said, there's no higher order functions here. HOF - is a function, that takes function(s) and RETURN FUNCTION. All ones listed above are voids.

Comment: Technically a higher order function can take a function as an argument or return a function. So this question shows a HOF but it’s not clear what the OP is running into trouble with. Please show a [mcve] that we can run to see the issue. Also read the linked question and see how specific the questions are, that makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is higher order function ?

> Functions that operate on other functions, **either** by taking them as
> arguments **or** by returning them, are called higher-order functions.

Let me start with a small example and then we get back to the problem in the question.

```js
function evenNumberFilter(number) {
  return number%2==0
}

function oddNumberFilter(number) {
  return !evenNumberFilter(number)
}

evenNumberFilter(2) // true
oddNumberFilter(3)  // true
```

Now we know if we call function

1. `evenNumberFilter` with `parameter X` it will return `true` if it is even number
2. `oddNumberFilter` with `parameter X` it will return `true` if it is odd number

Let's extend the problem and say

1. `"I would like to have all even numbers till number 10"`
2. `"I would like to have all odd numbers till number 10"`

```js
function evenNumberFilter(number) {
  return number %2 == 0
}

function oddNumberFilter(number) {
  return !evenNumberFilter(number)
}

function evenNumberBeforeTen() {
  const result = []
  for(number=0; number<10; number++) {
    if (evenNumberFilter(number)) {
      result.push(number)
    }
  }
  return result
}

function oddNumberBeforeTen() {
  const result = []
  for(number=0; number<10; number++) {
    if (oddNumberFilter(number)) {
      result.push(number)
    }
  }
  return result
}

evenNumberBeforeTen();  //[0,2,4,6,8]
oddNumberBeforeTen();   //[1,3,5,7,9]
```

If we look at the code both `evenNumberBeforeTen` and `oddNumberBeforeTen` share good amount of common code

1. The way for loop is itereated
2. The way result is appended to an array
3. The result that is returned at the end of the function.

Only difference between these two functions is, what `filter` it operates on either `evenNumberFilter` or `oddNumberFilter`.

So can we refactor the code and write one generic `filter` function which can take the **predicate** as a parameter ?

> **Predicate**: a boolean-valued function `P: X? {true, false}`.
>
> In our case both `evenNumberFilter` and `oddNumberFilter` are
> predicates

```js
function evenNumberFilter(number) {
  return number %2 == 0
}

function oddNumberFilter(number) {
  return !evenNumberFilter(number)
}

function filter(predicate) {
  const result = []
  for(number=0; number<10; number++) {
    if (predicate(number)) {
      result.push(number)
    }
  }
  return result
}

filter(evenNumberFilter);  //[0,2,4,6,8]
filter(oddNumberFilter);   //[1,3,5,7,9]
```

Now, in the above example function `filter` is higher order function because it takes function `predicate` as parameter.

Let's get into the problem you mentioned in the question.

`repeat` is a higher order function which takes `number` and function `action` as a parameter.

`unless` is a higher order function which takes `boolean` and function `then` as a parameter

When you execute

```
repeat(3, n => {
  unless(n%2 == 1, () => {
    console.log(`${n} is even`);
  });
});
```

1. `repeat` is called first and then it will execute function below 3 times.

```js
function (n) => {
  unless(n%2 == 1, () => {
    console.log(`${n} is even`);
});
```

2. When above function is called with parameters 0,1,2. It calls `unless` function with boolean of `n%2==1` which will be either `true` or `false` and function below as parameter.

```js
function() => {
  console.log(`${n} is even`);
});
```

When unless is called with `true` and `then` it will not execute the `then` function so no log is printed

When unless is called with `false` and `then` it will  execute the `then` function which prints the log

Comment: Hello, I want to take a moment and appreciate you for your answer. It's clear and simple it's starting to make sense now. Just let me know you got my comment. Coz the diamond moderator is deleting my comments whenever I try to thank or they downvote my question. This was my first question, anyways thanks a lot now I can continue again Eloquent JavaScript :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad the answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Higher-order functions either accept a function as a parameter, or return a function; both `unless` and `repeat` accept functions as parameters.

`repeat` accepts a number and a function, and simply calls whatever function was passed to it, that number of times.

`unless` accepts a value and a function; if the value is falsy then the function will be called.

What this demonstrates is that functions can be passed around just like any other variable: inside `repeat()`, `action` refers to the function itself, and `action()` calls that function to get its result.

Answer (score 0):

```
function repeat(n, action) {
 for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   action(i);
 }
}
```

n is the number of time you want execute the `action` function.

the `action` function is called here a callback function

if you do `repeat(5, console.log)` you gonna have:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

you can also execute another `function` like this

```
repeat(5, item => console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

// from this problem,  can a map be used

```
function evenNumberFilter(number) {
  return number %2 == 0
}
function oddNumberFilter(number) {
  return !evenNumberFilter(number)
}
function filter(predicate) {
  const result = []
  for(number=0; number<10; number++) {
    if (predicate(number)) {
      result.push(number)
    }
  }
  return result
}
filter(evenNumberFilter);  //[0,2,4,6,8]
filter(oddNumberFilter);   //[1,3,5,7,9]
```

// can a map be used for this
// rather than using an if statement pls can you  explain

// this is what i mean

```
 function mapNumber(predicate) {
     let result = [];
     for (let number = 0; number < 10; number++) {
             result.push(predicate(number))**

     }
     return result;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, ur unless function sounds like - take the condition, test it, then run the callback. The repeat func sounds like run action(s) n times. The result sounds like run action(s), and check inside if it satisfies the condition, then run unless function.